# Undefined Index Error in PHP Image Upload

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this line of code?  I am getting an error (yet the the page still functions properly despite the error)

Error:

```
"Notice: Undefined index: picture in C:\wamp\www\pplogin\members.php on line 180"
```

Here is the code:

```
179  $target = "user_images/fs/";
180  $target = $target . basename($_FILES['picture']['name']);
```

Like I said earlier despite the error the image gets uploaded to the destination and the image name is saved to my MySQL database.

I've been scratching my head for a while now...

Comment: Please `print_r($_FILES)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$target = !empty($_FILES['picture']['name']) ? $target.basename($_FILES['picture']['name']) : false;
```

Comment: This removed the error but now the image isn't saving to the destination or saving the path...

Comment: Do you have check if $target isn't false when you do the upload?

Comment: NM, works like a charm! I pasted it wrong! THANKS

Answer (score 1):

A file with id

```
picture
```

doesn't exist.

Use

```
isset()
```

to make sure It's set.

You can also use the ternary operator:

```
$img = isset($_FILES['picture']) ? $_FILES['picture'] : null;
```

Or something like that :)